# Transfer Function as Second Order Section

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

I'm using the Python Control Systems Library:
[Python Control Systems Library](https://python-control.readthedocs.io/en/0.8.3/#)

Using this library, I have created a 6th order transfer function of the following type:
control.xferfcn.TransferFunction

I would like to express this transfer function as a product of three second-order-sections (biquads).  I cannot figure out how to do this within the Python Control Systems Library, as there doesn't seem to be a function such as the scipy function [tfsos](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.tf2sos.html):
Nor can I figure out how to manipulate the transfer function into a form that can be used with scipy to use the tfsos function available in scipy.

Can anyone suggest a means to convert a transfer function of type "control.xferfcn.TransferFunction" to a product of second-order-sections?

Comment: Based on [control.TransferFunction](https://python-control.readthedocs.io/en/0.8.3/generated/control.TransferFunction.html), it looks like `sos = tf2sos(tf.num[0][0], tf.den[0][0])` might work, where `tf` is your `TransferFunction` instance.  That assumes you have a SISO transfer function.  If you have MIMO, you'll have to loop over the lists in the `num` and `den` attributes.  (I haven't tried this myself, so this is just a comment, not an answer.)

Comment: Hi Warren -- I tried your suggestion and it does appear to work.  I don't get the same answer as with matlab, but I need to study how scipy and matlab define tf2sos with options to see if I can explain the difference.  What I can say is that I get a useful looking result after trying your suggestion -- thank you!